# Where can I have my work reviewed?

Tags: designers, portfolio

I'm new to graphic design coming from a software development background. In this area, I can easily have feedback about my work by open-sourcing my code, participate to existing open-source projects, or simply [ask others what they think](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)...

At a moment I envisaged to participate to crowd-sourcing design sites, but changed my mind as [it seems finally to be a bad idea](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/2025/5088)...

So, where could I find the best comments and advice about my graphic design work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two are probably the best places on the 'net to get feedback on your designs:

- [Dribbble](http://dribbble.com/)
- [Deviant Art](http://www.deviantart.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I would check out some Graphic Design forums. They're different from Stack Exchange because they don't constrain to a QA format. Look around a few of them first and sign up for the one with lots of recent activity. I'm a member of one that's been around for about 15 years now but at this point we don't even talk much about design anymore and are just all friends. Not really sure which ones, if any, are still active these days:

https://www.google.com/search?q=graphic+design+forums&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Usability Testing Exchange](https://usability.testing.exchange) — it's a free & open-source place where you give feedback to other people, about their websites, logos, designs, demo videos and other things, ...

... And then you get back feedback about your own work — you can link to an image, or link to a website. You get back about as much feedback as you give to others, counted in characters.

Note, though, that some people at Usability Testing Exchange are new to design and UX, maybe just like you.

(I'm developing it. The homepage mentions websites and apps, but it works equally well for images & logos, if you type a link to e.g. a logo image instead of a website.)

Answer (score 2):

We have introduced a new place on our meta for this very thing! Enjoy!

[Post your Work In Progress (FKA: The Looking Glass)](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/post-your-work-in-progress-fka-the-looking-glass)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98634/discussion-on-answer-by-ryan-where-can-i-have-my-work-reviewed).

Answer (score 1):

Try for example [DeviantArt](http://www.deviantart.com/). This site has a vast community of artists in many different genres. Feedback is one of their main features (IMO).